Windows 11 (not upgraded) and now "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\" exists
I have Windows 11 installed, no upgrade from Windows 10. But I have "C:$WINDOWS.~BT" and a program SetupHost.exe, which is running. Is there something wrong here?

There is nothing wrong with your installation. Your system likely is simply pending to be updated to 24H2.

This info is readily available, found with the most cursory search. They're a Windows maintenance process and the folder it uses.

Today I see that there happened an update to 24H2
